# move_uploaded_file missing permissions?

Tags: php, windows, permissions

I have a `Windows Server 2008 R2` and use Windows Authentication for my website.

One functionality of my website is to upload files to a folder, `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\upload` using php.

The problem is that I keep getting the same error `"failed to open stream: Permission denied"`.

I Googled for hours and tried the solutions but nothing works.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to grant the "IUSR" access to the specified directory. This is a local user under which the IIS service is running.

To grant access to a specific folder:

1) Open the folder properties by clicking right and selecting properties. 
2) Go the permissions tab. Click on "Edit"
3) Next click on add, make sure you select the local computer under locations and type "IUSR"
4) Click on "OK", now assign the "modify" permission to this user.

That's all. Hope this helps. If this doesn't work, use [Microsoft process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to log denies to the file system. This should help you figure out which user tries to write to your file system.

Comment: I use the Windows authentication and the Server gets my Windows user when i authenticate (Pass-through-Authentication). If I use the anonymous authentication then i need the IUSR but not here :)

Comment: Ok understood. Can you run process monitor to check what user tries to write? Then give that user or group the permission on the same way as described above.

Comment: The process Monitor showed me that the application uses the apppool user. I wonder why???. I need the windows user who is logged in... Not everyone should be able to upload something or display something uploaded... Now i have to grant the 'IIS APPPOOL\<Username>' all rights but thats no way because of securtiy reasons.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but did you disable the anonymous authentication?

Comment: yes of course. The only authentication method which is enabled, is the Windows authentication.